# Use MySQL datatypes in Apache Derby

Tags: mysql, hibernate, derby

Is there a way to use MySQL data-types in Apache Derby? I am trying to make my application supportive of multiple databases and datatypes such as datetime, mediumtext are available in MySQL and not in Apache Derby. So is there a way to make Derby compatible with MySQL?

Comment: Are you using Java?

Comment: Yes, I am using Java

Comment: If you are using JPA and Hibernate then it will work across multiple databases out of the box. Is there a special requirement here?